# Tampermonkey Script - getComputedStyle(variable).display inconsistency

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I am trying to make a script that only triggers on certain conditions on a web tool.

There are two text blocks, when one is active, the style inspector says says:
style="display: block"
and the other is
style="display: none"

When I use a command like the following though

`console.log("Block status is: " + getComputedStyle(element1).display);`
Output is: block (as expected)

`console.log("Block status is: " + getComputedStyle(element2).display);`
Output is: block (despite style inspector saying "none")

When printing the whole object using:
`console.log(getComputedStyle(element1).display); console.log(getComputedStyle(element2).display);`
Delving into them, they both say block, even though only one is displayed and the style inspector saying only one is displayed.

They are both a very simple class and I don't have much to work with when it comes to triggering an action based on their state. Can anyone help clarify what is happening here or recommend any alternative solutions?

Comment: It means the style is changed by the site after your script runs or there's a rule with !important that overrides the inline style.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the input! I do have this script running on a clock too and after each second it checks the status again and still says both are "block". Can you recommend any other method of checking which is visible?

Comment: The best method IMO is IntersectionObserver.